# Know if external url was accessed in python

Tags: python, url, flask, external

I want to build a webscraping application in python to know if a url that is outside my domain is accessed. Can I do it with flask endpoint?

Something like:

```
app.route('https://www.example.com/?userid=1',method=['GET'])
def count_acces(id_user):
   <code>
   return id_user
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **requests** module. Check out more [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/)

```
import requests

try:
    url = "https://some_wrong_url.wrong"
    requests.request("GET", url)
except requests.RequestException as e:
    print(e)
```